# Why do some operators return DataFrame while others Dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for the reason why under SPARK 2.3.1. this returns a DF as I expect:

```
val df = Seq(
 Person(0, "AgataZ", 0),
 Person(1, "Iweta", 0),
 Person(71, "Gloria", 222), 
 Person(3333, "Maksym", 0)).toDF("k","n","p")

df:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [k: integer, n: string ... 1 more fields]
```

but this returns a DS:

```
val rdd  = sc.parallelize(scala.util.Random.shuffle(1 to 1000000))
val df = rdd.map(x => (randomInt1toLarge, randomInt1toVeryLarge, x))
        .toDF("time_asc", "device", "trip_init").persist

df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [time_asc: int, device: int ... 1 more field]
```

DS, DF interchangeable, possibly trivial, but curious none-the-less. I cannot see the exact reason for the decision to be made by Spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** See the signatures.

`toDF` belongs to [DatasetHolder](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DatasetHolder) and the signature is as follows:

```
toDF(colNames: String*): DataFrame
```

[Dataset.persist](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@persist():Dataset.this.type) looks as follows:

```
persist(): Dataset.this.type
```

"Why?" you ask. `DataFrame` is always the preferred way to work with large datasets due to performance benefits (e.g. no deserialization for things like ordering) while `Dataset` is more pleasant for Scala developers for its type safety.

Just to make things clear, it's all about encoders used and `Dataset` is a type constructor with `DataFrame` being a type alias for `Dataset[Row]` with RowEncoder.

Also note that [Dataset](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) API is divided to 5 groups with **Typed transformations** and **Untyped transformations** amongst them.

Comment: Great stuff. Getting there